# Смысл использования оператора echo в теге meta

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование, книги

В книге Лауры Томсон "Разработка Web-приложений на PHP и MySQL" написано в главе про объектно-ориентированное программирование следующее:

1. Большинство коммерческих Web-страниц включают в себя метадескрипторы, помогающие поисковым механизмам выполнять их индексацию. Чтобы они были полезны, метадескрипторы, вероятно, должны изменяться от страницы к странице. В этом случае мы также определяем значение по умолчанию (эта есть атрибут класса Page):

   ```
   var $keywords = "TLA Consulting, Three Letter Abbreviation,
   some of my best friends are search engines";
   ```
2. Затем несколько спустя приводится код, в котором используется эта переменная вместе с метатегом:

   ```
   function DisplayKeywords
   {
      echo "<META name=\"keywords\" content=\"$this->keywords\">"
   }
   ```

   Объясните зачем используется оператор `echo` для html тега `META` ( ), если  meta задает ключевые слова для индексации поисковиками (стр. 149-156 Лауры Томсон "Разработка Web приложений на PHP и MySQL").

Answer (score 1):

Я считаю, что это немного не рационально так выводить ключевые слова.

Лучше будет так. Например в контроллере определяется переменная `$keywords`, а в виде надо делать так:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $keywords; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем удачный пример в книге как по мне. Я бы сделал так:

Изначально есть дефолтные кейвордсы:

```
protected $_keywords = "one, two, three";
```

Для этого свойства геттер и сеттер:

```
public function getKeywords()
{
    return $this->_keywords;
}

public function setKeywords($keywords)
{
    $this->_keywords = $keywords;
    return $this;
}
```

В процессе контроллер сеттит нужные кейвордс для текущей страницы:

```
$keywords = "word1, word2, word3";
$this->setKeywords($keywords);
```

И уже при выводе html при помощи геттера:

```
<meat name="keywords" content="<?php echo $this->getKeywords();?>">
```