# Результат действия оператора echo для тега meta

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование, книги

**Прошу не закрывать вопрос и обязательно прочесть его содержание**

Я уже задавал подобный вопрос на [Смысл использования оператора echo в теге meta](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/242481/php-%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-echo-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B5-meta) , но не совсем получил на него ответ, так как не совсем четко сформулировал вопрос. Вопрос состоит в том: что делает оператор echo для тега meta - он выводит ключевые слова, использующиеся при индексации поисковиками, на экран или же что-то другое, т. к. функция использующаяся `DisplayKeywords` участвует в отображении следующей страницы:

[image]

А я что-то не наблюдаю всех слов, указанных в переменной `keywords`

```
var $keywords = "TLA Consulting, Three Letter Abbreviation,
some of my best friends are search engines";
```

поэтому и задал этот вопрос.

Comment: Сожгите книгу, которая не может объяснить читателю принцип «клиент— сервер».

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Вы путаете понятия, смотрите:**

- echo оператор вывода PHP(!!!), выводит данные (грубо говоря: формирует вашу HTML страничку)
- meta это тег HTML(!!!), который в вашем контексте определяет ключевые слова (keywords) для вашей HTML странички
- слова из <meta keywords=""/> не отображаются в теле страницы, пользователь их не увидит, они созданы только поисковых машин

**Важно понимать:**

- Оператору echo (как и print, я не вижу разницы) не важно что выводить, будь то "meta keywords=\"keys, keys\">", или скажем "<b>my blow text</b>" или что угодно.
- Оператора echo нет и не может быть для какого то "именно конкретного тега" (в вашем вопросе meta)
- Помните: PHP работает на стороне сервера, HTML на стороне клиента (в браузере)

**Ну и для примера как это работает (в общих чертах на начальном уровне):**

а) Некий скрипт PHP генерирует текст с помощью echo и print из кусков

```
<?php 
echo "<html>";
echo "<meta charset=\"utf-8\">";
echo "<meta keywords=\"keys\">";
echo "<body>";
$a=10+15;
echo "Любой текст, результат: " . $a . "</body></html>";
?>
```

б) Как только скрипт закончил работу браузер сразу загрузит страничку, состоящую из "блоков" которые вы "отдали"(распечатали, сгенерировали) операторами echo\print

*Мы получим примерно следующее:*

```
<html> 
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta keywords="keys">
<body>
Любой текст, результат: 25
</body></html>
```

в) Браузер тут же загрузит это и отобразит у пользователя и он никогда не узнает из скольки "эхо"(и\или мат вычислений, обращений в базу, генераций кусков шаблона и тд) она состояла.

P.S> Про экранирование ковычек (`\"`) и перевод каретки (`\n\r`) полно описания в интернете, удачи :)